# Using yarn to add a package in angular2

Tags: angular, nvd3.js, yarnpkg

I am still new to yarn and angular2 so excuse any naivety in this question.

I am trying to use yarn to add nvd3 to my project so I ran `yarn add @types/nvd3 --save-dev` and then added `import { nv } from 'nvd3'` in the main `module.ts` but that isn't compiling with the error `Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/omitted/omitted/node_modules/@types/nvd3/index"' has no exported member 'nv'.`

However, in `nodemodules/@types/nvd3/index.d.ts` there is a `export = nv;`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually install the library, with

npm install nvd3 --save

You only installed the "types" for it, you need both.